# Calculating bending modulus of a CG model of a surface from MD simulation

Tags: molecular-dynamics, gromacs, martini

I have built a CG (Martini) model of a 2D Nanomaterial. For now, I want to calculate its bending rigidity. As far as I know, the bending modulus can be computed by making the nanomaterial infinite - i.e. cross over the PBC which will allow stretching.

Has anyone done similar work with gromacs? and is my current level of knowledge is correct on making the nanomaterial infinite by adding the bonded terms between the two ends.

Looking forward to some suggestions with regards to this. Thank you.

Comment: I really don't thing that using PBC will help you as the idea of PBC is not having an infinite material. Maybe you will need to have a very large cell instead.

Comment: You need to set ```periodic-molecules=yes``` in ```mdp``` file. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks @NightShade, I have. I am just trying to know, if my current understanding on calculating bending modulus is right/not.

Comment: Did it work Roshan? Please update us! I gave my +1 long ago, but am curious if trying what the commenters advised, lead to an answer to your question.